# How to distribute / access data files in Python egg?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, egg

I'm writing a Django application that is using pip & virtualenv to manage its development environment.

One of the dependencies, [pkgme](http://pkgme.net), comes with many data files which are its "backends" and are configured in its setup.py with `data_files=$FOO` (rather than `package_data`).

When pkgme looks for its backends, it looks in `os.path.join(sys.prefix, "share", "pkgme", "backends")`. This works great when pkgme has been installed normally, and seems to match the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files) but does *not* work when pkgme is installed as an egg.

There, the data files are installed under `$VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkgme-0.1-py2.7.egg/share` rather than the expected `$VIRTUAL_ENV/share`.

Which leaves me with two questions:

1. Should I be using something other than the `os.path.join` above to find the data files regardless of whether we are using an egg installation or a traditional system installation? If so, what?
2. Should I be distributing my data files differently so as to make them more readily available in an egg?

Note that I know about `pkgutil.get_data`, but would rather not use it. I'm not interested in the *contents* of these data files, I want to know their *location* instead, so I can execute them.

My current plan is to do this:

- Use `package_data` instead of `data_files`
- Change pkgme to look for backends relative to `pkgme.__file__` rather than `sys.prefix`

Comment: Consider setting `zip_safe` to False in your setup.py so it doesn't generate a .egg file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

- Changing pkgme to use `pkg_resources.resource_filename()` to find its own included backends
- Added an entry point that any backend written in Python can use to publish the location of its own backend scripts
- Kept the `sys.prefix`-based check for any backend that don't want to use Python

The diff can be found here: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~pkgme-committers/pkgme/trunk/revision/86

Answer (score 2):

Your current plan is essentially correct, or is at any rate a workable option.

When setuptools creates an egg, it checks whether code in the egg makes use of `__file__`, and if so, it marks the egg as not being installable in compressed form.  In this way, when the egg is installed by easy_install, it'll get extracted to an `.egg/` directory instead of being left in an `.egg` file.

If you want to support compressed/drop-in installation (i.e., just dumping the egg in a directory without "installing" it), then you should use the `pkg_resources.resource_filename()` [(docs here)](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PkgResources#resource-extraction) API instead of `__file__`, but then your package will be dependent on setuptools or distribute in order to have that API available.

Comment: Thanks PJE. Good to know about the `__file__` checking. I went with a similar approach to the one I suggested in the question, but with the additional use of entry points to handle some backends.